# jQuery.sap.equal compare ordering

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I'm comparing two objects (`nested objects`) using `jQuery.sap.equal`:
these objects include nested tables.
They both contain same values but not the same order and `jQuery.sap.equal`  returns `false`. Is there a way to make it ignore the order?
Thanks!

example :

```
jQuery.sap.equal(
[
  { a: "b" },
  { c: "d" }
],
[
  { c: "d" },
  { a: "b" }
]) 
returns false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the API of [jQuery.sap.equal](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.equal),

> Compares the two given values for equality, especially takes care not to compare arrays and objects by reference, but compares their content. Note: function does not work with comparing XML objects.

If you compare objects it will work but you have to handle for arrays.

For Objects:

```
jQuery.sap.equal(
 {
   x : { a: "b" },
   y : { c: "d" }
 },
{
  y : { c: "d" },
  x : { a: "b" }
});
```

will return `true`